# Create array and total values obtained from using StreamReader

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I figured out how to read a text file using `StreamReader`. Now I must create an array and Total all the values in `index[1]`, the price.

**My data reads as follows:**

> yellow cab, 62.12, 10/17/16
>
> chick fil a, 9.50, 10/18/16

I currently only have 10 lines, however, there could be more added in the future.

I want to add 62.12 and 9.50 and enter the Total in `txtBox_Total.text = Total.ToString();`

**Here is my current code:**

```
private void btn_CalculateLoadExpenses_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currentLine;
    // Create StreamReader object to read Exams.txt
    StreamReader examsReader = new StreamReader("TravelExpenses.txt");

    listBox_Output.Items.Clear();

    while (examsReader.EndOfStream == false)
    {
        currentLine = examsReader.ReadLine();
        listBox_Output.Items.Add(currentLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines` is a lot easier as suggested in the answer of Damith. In case you really want to use a `StreamReader` for some case or the other, you should **close** the reader after using it or wrap  the stream in a `using` statement. `File.ReadAllLines` will do this for you automatically.

Comment: @Jim: Easier but much slower in the meantime. StreamReader is way better.

Comment: @Transcendent yes that is correct, my comment does not imply that `File.ReadAllLines` is faster. But indeed it's worth to mention what the pro and contras are. Thanks. ... I have to mention this also depends on what the size of the file is. If the file only contains e.g. 20 lines ... the difference would be *0.007 ms* more or less.

Comment: @Jim: The beauty of programing is that, unlike mathematics, in programming there's more than one solution to a problem and they differ in terms of performance and efficiency. Accordingly each one of these solutions may suite only a certain case. And yeah here, `RealAllLines` can be appropriate while elsewhere it may be inefficient.

Comment: @Transcendent I agree completely :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can read all lines at ones using `File.ReadAllLines`

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("TravelExpenses.txt");
```

then add all using `Items.AddRange`

```
listBox_Output.Items.AddRange(lines );
```

sum an be taken from the strings by splitting and taking sum of numbers like below

```
var Total= lines.Select(line =>line.Split(',')[1]).Select(num =>decimal.Parse(num)).Sum();
txtBox_Total.text = Total.ToString();
```

Comment: `ReadAllLines` is pretty slow. Using `ReadLine` method in `StreamReader` is a potentially faster method for reading files. And your linqish approach also makes the whole thing slower.

Comment: Yes, that's true. but it depends on the file size, you will not notice the performance gain for small file. ( 1 million records showing on listbox is not practical)

Comment: Well, I work on data mining projects very often where I need to load large plain text files. I have noticed that the `ReadAllLines` can simply lag annoyingly on text files containing 10,000 lines and more. This size for plain text files is not uncommon (in real world case scenarios) and that's why I commented on your post, else for small files your approach would be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I must use StreamReader for this assignment. I have posted an answer to my question that is still incorrect. I would appreciate if you could take a look one more time. I am getting an answer of 0 for my total.

Answer (score 0):

I must use StreamReader for this assignment. Here is more code I have written. Something is still incorrect as my total is not working. I am afraid I am making this more complicated than it needs to be.

private void btn_CalculateLoadExpenses_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        string[] purchase = new string[10];
        float[] price = new float[10];

        int index = 0;

        string currentLine;
        string[] fields;
        float purchaseTotal, total = 0;
        // Create StreamReader object to read Exams.txt
        StreamReader examsReader = new StreamReader("TravelExpenses.txt");

        listBox_Output.Items.Clear();

        while (examsReader.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            currentLine = examsReader.ReadLine();
            fields = currentLine.Split(',');
            listBox_Output.Items.Add(currentLine);

            purchase[index] = fields[0];
            price[index] = total;

            index++;
            purchaseTotal = total;

            txt_Box_Total.Text = total.ToString();
        }

        examsReader.Close();
    }
```